# background image not showing on CSS Div

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code:

```
#type_box {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:5px;
    border-radius:20px;
}
.box_okay {
    background:url(/images/tick.png) no-repeat;
}
.box_none {
    background:#000000;
}
.box_Warning {
    background:url(/images/tick.png) no-repeat;
}
.box_Error {
    background:url(/images/cross.png) no-repeat;
}
.box_Maintenance {
    background:url(/images/spanner.png) no-repeat;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div id="type_box" class="box_okay"></div>
<div id="type_box" class="box_Warning"></div>
<div id="type_box" class="box_Error"></div>
<div id="type_box" class="box_Maintenance"></div>
```

but the images are not showing - here is an example: *http://jsfiddle.net/42usL/*

Comment: All good on your jsFiddle example. Did you check if the images paths are correct?

Comment: ids should be unique to a single element on the page. You are using them incorrectly. `type_box` should be a class.

Answer (score 5):

Your images are loading, but the `<div>` elements are too small to see it.

Change to:

```
#type_box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

to see it. [Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42usL/3/).

Also, you have multiple`<div>` elements with the same ID. This is not a valid document, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: 30px 30px;`

The background images aren't being sized so you're only seeing a little part of them.

[Fiddle using "contains"](http://jsfiddle.net/42usL/2/)

[Fiddle using "pixel size"](http://jsfiddle.net/42usL/4/)

```
#type_box {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:5px;
    border-radius:20px;
}
.box_okay {
    background:url(http://s22.postimg.org/o4zp9zeu5/tick.png) no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
.box_none {
    background:#000000;
}
.box_Warning {
    background:url(http://s22.postimg.org/o4zp9zeu5/tick.png) no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
.box_Error {
    background:url(http://s8.postimg.org/juv72insx/cross.png) no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
.box_Maintenance {
    background:url(http://s22.postimg.org/d6ofrsq8t/spanner.png) no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
```